# Airflow webserver also starts worker

Tags: airflow

Question: why does `airflow webserver` also start the workers?

I've been googling on how to build Airflow service as I'll need to build a few environments (Prod the last). I've found a great blog that says that different roles can be started different which suits my needs, e.g.:

```
$ airflow webserver
$ airflow scheduler
$ airflow worker
```

But then I realized that `airflow webserver` also starts the workers and I also found the following parameter in the config file:

```
# Number of workers to run the Gunicorn web server
workers = 4
```

My guess is these 4 workers are only for running the web server, but not running the tasks. Is that correct?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct, that setting is for web workers for the webserver. Gunicorn being the HTTP server.  The webserver will never actually run a task.  It will always be via processes running `airflow worker` (or if you are using the LocalExecutor, the scheduler will run them)